# Should I use PHP Sockets for a multiplayer Flash game

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, websocket, multiplayer

I need to build a multiplayer card game in AS3 and I want to know the best way to communicate between players.  I am currently sending game data into a database and having AS3 call a PHP page every second to query that database and check for updates on player actions. However, I've read somewhere that this is a bad approach, and that the correct way would be to use PHP sockets.  So I have a few questions:

1) Using my current method (non-socket), how many simultaneous users would I be able to support if they all queried the database every second for changes to the card deck and player turns.

2) Could someone give an explanation on PHP sockets. It's a new subject for me and I'd like to know their advantages and how they work. I've searched many tutorials but haven't found any recent ones that gave a simple explanation, nor was I able to get any of them to work.

3) What are the prerequisites for using PHP sockets? I only have intermediate experience with PHP and Flash and I am wondering if this project is too advanced for me to handle. I have no other formal programming background (e.g. Software engineering, C++, Java, command line) and I was wondering if this project would be an impossible uphill battle for me.

Thanks.

Comment: off topic, but I don't know anyone still writing Flash code. How come you're not writing it in HTML5?

Comment: I've given up Flash long ago for HTML/PHP. But have recently gone back in order to build a rather complex multiplayer game. Would that be possible/easier in HTML5?

Comment: I know other people are doing it, so it's possible. Whether it's easier or not depends on how comfortable you are with the two technologies. It may well be easier in Flash if you're a good Flash dev. But the downsides are that some very popular platforms do not support Flash at all now, so you'll miss out on a lot of your potential audience.

Comment: Yeah I have heard that Flash is going down, which is why I also hesitate to learn it.  But it's still currently possible to port flash apps into other platforms (e.g. Flash to iPad). I'm equally comfortable in HTML5 as I am with Flash. I'm only afraid that HTML5 has a more difficult development environment (for games) and less documentation

Comment: I'm just worried about the learning curve that comes with those those servers, also a the user trial limit.  The game I'm developing is more turn based than fully synchronus.  Would using a standard PHP socket still be feasible for 100+ current connections? What about repeated Http requests?

Comment: @Spudley I thought Adobe AIR isn't going down on mobiles. It is pretty much same thing as Flash.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer to your question, but have you considered using an available multiplayer API/server? I've played around with [player.io](http://playerio.com/) and thought it was really easy to get going. There is another similar one that I can't remember the name for, but both have a free service level to get coding on. If nothing else, it can expose you to some of the stuff that is being handled by the server, and the kind of issues that are involded in client-server communication. Player.io uses C, and also has some good articles on their website.

Comment: Yeah I've ran across it during my research.  I'm in a bit of a hurry to finish my project though and don't have time to get comfortable with a new API/Server or C. If the game can be built efficiently with Flash/PHP/Socket I'd rather do that.